# Get the number of time a moq method has been called

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, moq

It's possible to use `myMock.Verify(m => m.f(It.IsAny<string>()), ...);` to assert that the method `f(string s)` has been called at least / at most / exactly n times.

I want to do something a bit more complicated: I want to ensure that the number of calls to `f(string s)` *plus* the number of calls to `f(int i)` is equal to 3.

Is there an lightweight way to do it with Moq?

**More details**

Actually I can think of a way to do it: I could setup a callback that would increment a counter when each of those methods is used. However it would require more set up in the test, which could hinder it's readability. (And it would be a shame to re-implement something that could already be implemented in moq).

For instance a lightweight way to do it could be to be able to retrieve the exact number of call to my method, so that I could `Assert.AreEqual` on it. But I haven't been able to find a way to do it so far.

Comment: I would use the way you are thinking of. Declare `var calls = 0;`, then append `.Callback(() => calls++)` to the setups of `f(string)` and `f(int)`. The [cheat sheet](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) uses `.Callback(() => calls++)` as an example. In my opinion, the readability of this is really good.

Comment: Here is an example of what what @Jeppe-Stig-Nielsen is talking about: [testing-a-method-called-many-times-in-moq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354937/testing-a-method-called-many-times-in-moq)